# How identify appropriate QGIS archive for given OS

Tags: qgis

I want to download version 3.10 on a Mac, but the archived versions in the "All Releases" tab of the download window are not named in a way that distinguishes a Mac version from W32 or W64.
For example, which of the following would I download for installing 3.10 on a Mac? (yes, I have reasons to need the most recently expired LTR)

[   ]   QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.14-1-Setup-x86.exe    16-Jan-2021 09:17   336M
[   ]   QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.14-1-Setup-x86.exe.sha256sum  16-Jan-2021 09:17   103
[   ]   QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.14-1-Setup-x86_64.exe 16-Jan-2021 09:24   386M
[   ]   QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.14-1-Setup-x86_64.exe.sha256sum   16-Jan-2021 09:24   106

Comment: All of the files listed are for Windows, as they have .exe in the name. You are looking for a file ending in .dmg

Answer (score 1):

There is a Window folder and a Mac folder. The Mac folder is actually a bit misleading (`/macos/` AND `/macOS/`, which have different content).

https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/ltr/

Comment: Thanks so mcc for this!